# Keeping my Macbook synched with Mac. Same files same programs.

Tags: macos, mac, development

Most of the time I am working on my mac on development. I have my terminal the way i want it. The files are also here. I only use the macbook when I go out or need to work on programming classes.

Is there anyway that I can keep both my computers synced. So I don't have to fix the settings on each one when I use it.

I want this for convenience also but mainly because when I go out and use it is when I notice I don't have something I use on the Mac and it's a pain to setup everything and a waste of time.

Comment: The only way I know of to competely replicate the system state is to disk image the mac on a weekly/daily basis and copy to the Macbook, then boot that image as a VM on the macbook when on the road.

Comment: I will search if there is a program that can automate this. Since this can take some time.